# Few questions... ModelState.IsValid and Grouped CheckBox Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, checkbox, modelstate, code-first

Using ASP.NET MVC when I create my model, then a controller based on the model with CRUD operations, the CRUD views are generated. I added some code using Fluent API to require certain fields but for some reason the ModelState.IsValid passes even when these fields are not completed. What determines whether this passes or not? I thought it was based on your model property data types and other things like being required or maxlength, etc....

Also, I have manually added code to grab a list of Categories from the database and generate a checkbox for each one in the View. This is a navigation property for the Project model where there is a many-many relationship. To get the group of checked values in the Create(Project project) method in the controller I use:

```
var selected = Request["categories"].Split(',');
```

This however, throws the classic Object reference not set to an instance of an object error if no values are checked. So what I want to know is, how can I determine that this does not have any values so I can do something else once detected?

Comment: if you have two separate problems, you should have two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added some code **using Fluent API** to require certain fields but for
>   some reason the ModelState.IsValid passes even when these fields are
>   not completed.

ASP.NET MVC doesn't know anything about the Fluent API of Entity Framework and doesn't evaluate this configuration. You only can use the data annotations which MVC will recognize:

```
[Required]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

---

> ...how can I determine that this does not have any values so I can do
>   something else once detected?

Not sure if I understand it correctly but I'd say:

```
var categories = Request["categories"];
if (categories != null)
{
    var selected = categories.Split(',');
    // ...
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, so for the first part... So does this mean I should replicate it in the model as a data annotation? Just seems redundant. I thought you could do everything in Fluent API that you can do in data annotations but more. 

Second part makes sense, I'll try it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1066133: Yes, you can do everything in Fluent API that you can do with annotations. But this is only the case for Entity Framework itself. EF evaluates both, but not ASP.NET MVC. This infamous `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace is very confusing. The `[Required]` attribute for example has a double-purpose. It's read by MVC (for emitting client validation Javascript code and for server side validation) and by EF to define the database schema. But this is totally different code and the attribute existed in MVC before EF.

Comment: Well then I guess I'm just gonna' have to put some data annotations and some fluent api? Is this a bad practice or is it common practice?

Comment: @user1066133: I'd say it's bad practice (unless perhaps for very small applications). Good practice would be to use ViewModels for your Views and Models for your database access and then map between the two. The problem disappears then because you would use the MVC annotations on the ViewModels and the EF annotations or Fluent API for the Models.

Comment: Ok I'll do some more research on your suggestions. Thanks again for your help.